# Replace all values if between Two of the Same Value with Wraparound

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I am trying to replace all values if between two of the same value, with wraparound. Since this is wordy, what I would like to do is:

I have this array (there are only 3 distinct values):

- w - white,
- o - orange,
- y - yellow.

If a white is in between two of the same color, paint it that color.

```
[w, o, w, w, y, y, o, w, o, y, o, w]
```

After doing the replacement, it would look like:

```
[o, o, w, w, y, y, o, o, o, y, o, o]
```

Here is what I have so far (`n` is the length of the array):

```
def initialPaint():
    for i in range(0, n):
        curr = arr[i]
        mid = arr[(i + 1) % n]
        last = arr[(i + 2) % n]

        if mid == "w" and curr == last:
            arr[(i + 1) % n] = curr
```

I think the wraparound works, because of the % n part.The issue is that if there is a portion like: [... o, w, w, o, ...] it doesn't paint those two whites to orange.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if there is more clarification needed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to *extend* the list on both borders and iterate over the extended list:

```
lst = ['w', 'o', 'w', 'w', 'y', 'y', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'y', 'o', 'w']

def paint(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return lst
    new_lst = [lst[1]] + lst + [lst[-2]]
    return [v1 if v1==v3 and v2=='w' else v2 for v1, v2, v3 in zip(new_lst, new_lst[1:], new_lst[2:])]

print( paint(lst) )
```

Prints:

```
['o', 'o', 'w', 'w', 'y', 'y', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'y', 'o', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions could be

```
inp=['w', 'o', 'w', 'w', 'y', 'y', 'o', 'w', 'w', 'o', 'y', 'o', 'w']
d=dict()
#store indices in dictionary
for i in range(len(inp)):
    if inp[i]!='w':
        if d.get(inp[i])!=None:
            d[inp[i]].append(i)
        else:
            d[inp[i]]=[i]
# for 'w' in mid
for each in d:
    l=d[each]
    if len(l)>1:
        for i in range(len(l)-1):
            flag=0
            for j in range(l[i]+1,l[i+1]):
                flag=0
                if inp[j]=='w':
                    flag=1
                else:
                    flag=0
                    break

        if flag==1:
            for j in range(l[i]+1,l[i+1]):
                inp[j]=each
#for 'w' at beginning
for i in range(len(inp)):
    if inp[i]!='w':
        for j in range(i):
            inp[j]=inp[i]
        break
#for 'w at end'
for i in range(len(inp)-1,-1,-1):
    if inp[i]!='w':

        for j in range(i+1,len(inp)):
            inp[j]=inp[i]
        break
print(inp)
```

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57632734/7694474 given below is incorrect as it doesn't account for [...,'o','w','w','o',....] case, in which both w's should be painted with 'o'.